# Postsharp Include all methods except constructors

Tags: c#-4.0, postsharp

If I have an MethodInterceptionAspect how can I define it to include all methods in the class it is intercepting except for the constructors?

For example something along the following lines appears not to work...

```
[MyAspect(AttributeTargetMembers="regex:!.cctor|.*")]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to apply your attribute to class with `AttributeTargetElements = MulticastTargets.Method`. It targets methods (but not constructors).

This should do the trick:

```
[MyAspect(AttributeTargetElements = MulticastTargets.Method)]
```